# Curator - InterProcessMutex lock does not delete nodes

Tags: java, apache-zookeeper, apache-curator

*Does anybody know which of the Curator lock recipes creates ephemeral nodes ?*

I tested `InterProcessMutex` lock but as far as I can see (with the `zkClient`) it does not delete the nodes after release or close the session.

This is the code I'm using for lock keys.

```
public void lock(final LockKey lockkey, final LockAcquiredListener listener) throws Exception {

    final String lockKeyPath = lockkey.toString();

    LOGGER.info("Trying to acquire the lock {}", lockKeyPath);

    final InterProcessMutex lock = new InterProcessMutex(client, LOCKS_PREFIX + lockKeyPath);

    if (!lock.acquire(LOCK_MS_TIME_OUT, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)) {
        LOGGER.info("Could not acquire the lock {}", lockkey.toString());
        throw new LockAcquisitionTimeOutException("Could not acquire the lock: " + lockKeyPath);
    }
    try {
        if (listener != null) {
            LOGGER.info("Lock acquired for key {}", lockKeyPath);
            listener.lockAcquired(lockkey);
        }
    } finally {
        LOGGER.info("Release acquired key {}", lockKeyPath);
        lock.release();
    }
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: can you go into more detail regarding your statement "as far as I can see"?  in my look into the code, i see it does delete the path upon release

Comment: Yes, In Zookeper Client I can see the node after released the lock [zk: localhost:2181(CONNECTED) 7] ls /notifier/locks 
[testtestgrouped]
This corresponde with the persistence node behaviour.

Comment: Have you got a solution for this issue? I am also facing a similar issue with InterProcessSemaphoreMutex under high loads where it is working fine under regular load conditions.